# Set table row position with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to set the position of a table row with jquery and this is how I am doing it

```
top_position = $("#table_id").offset().top;
$("#table_id tr:nth-child(1)").offset().top = top_position;
```

This does not change the table row I am trying to change. But when I try this:

```
alert(top_position);
table_row_position = $("#table_id tr:nth-child(1)").offset().top; 
alert(table_row_position);
```

I get both positions correctly alerted, so why doesn't resetting the position work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Core/index](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/index) function in a given context, for example you can check the index of the TD in it's parent TR to get the column number, and you can check the TR index on the Table, to get the row number:
You can try something like :

```
$('#table_id tr td').click(function(){
  var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
  var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
  alert('Row: ' + row + ', Column: ' + col);
});
```

Check a running example [**here**](http://jsbin.com/eyeyu/edit).

Answer (score 0):

.offset().top will tell you where something is but you should be using css to move the object so try something like this.

```
$("#table_id tr:nth-child(1)").css("margin-top", top_position);
```

see this for more information

http://api.jquery.com/offset/